# STILL overfitting image classification for CheXpert dataset

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, classification

I try to classify images from CheXpert dataset on only one of the observations (Alectasis) and a **2 class classification** problem (1 true, 0 false).
I preprocess the images by resizing them to 224x224 and normalizing them. I used 30,000 pictures for training (10% validation) and 7,500 test images.
As a model I am using a **pretrained ResNet34** on ImageNet.
When running the model it is overfitting: training loss decreases to 0.043 wheareas the validation loss rises to 2.199 which leads to a test accuracy of 55.56%.
I tried following attempts to prevent the overfitting:

#*Attempt 1*: I used a classifier with dropout layers

-> Validation loss decreased in the beginning but after 6 epochs it was rising again

#*Attempt 2*: I added dropout layers in the whole model

-> Validation loss decreased in the beginning but model converged very slowly. After some epochs, validation loss increased and model also converged faster

#*Attempt 3*: I froze all nonlinear layers and fitted the model only on the last linear layer

-> Network did not seem to converge at all, not even after 50 epochs

Making the classification task a binary classification task also changed nothing. Trying the same things with a DenseNet121 also didn't change a lot.

```
class ResNet(FitModule):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=2):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.net = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=True)
        # Change classifier
        kernel_count = self.net.fc.in_features
        self.net.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(kernel_count, 500), nn.Linear(500, num_classes))
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        # Attempt 1: use classifier with dropout layers
        '''
        self.net.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.BatchNorm1d(kernel_count),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Linear(in_features=kernel_count, out_features=500),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(500),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Linear(in_features=500, out_features=num_classes))
        '''


    def freeze_nonlinear_layers(self):
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.conv1)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.bn1)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.relu)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.maxpool)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.layer1)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.layer2)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.layer3)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.layer4)
        self._freeze_layer(self.net.avgpool)


    def _freeze_layer(self, layer, freeze=True):
        if freeze:                              
            for p in layer.parameters():
                p.requires_grad = False
        else:                                   
            for p in layer.parameters():
                p.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Attempt 2: build whole network with dropout layers
        '''
        out = self.net.conv1(inputs)
        out = self.net.bn1(out)
        out = self.net.relu(out)
        out = self.net.maxpool(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.net.layer1(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.net.layer2(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.net.layer3(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.net.layer4(out)
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.net.avgpool(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.net.fc(out)
        '''
        # Attempt 3: freeze nonlinear layers and only train last linear layer
        '''
        self.freeze_nonlinear_layers
        '''
        return out/self.net(inputs) # attempt 2/attempt 1,3
```

To sum things up: Either the network does not converge or the validation loss rises and the test accuracy is poor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding new transforms to your train images. For example you might want to add a random rotation or random horizontal flip. All of the available transforms can be found here [pytorch transforms](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html). This is what I usually do if my model is over fitting. Do not add them to your validation or test set they are only for the training images.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried `transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=5)` and `transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)`. But after 4 epochs, the val loss started rising again and the resulting test accuracy was poor. Do you have another idea?

Comment: For your random rotation you probably want the degrees to be closer to 90. A 5 degree turn is not big at all. Also have you tried lowering your learning rate. What is it currently?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try with freezing upto layer 3 and try training the model for first 10 epochs. If you are not seeing any problem of overfitting, try to reduce the learning rate and proceed accordingly. Let us know if that worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your approach but the validation loss started rising directly after the first epoch. Do you have other ideas?